# The term 'livingdoc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if

Tags: c#, testing, specflow

I am trying to generate the livingdoc through my feature files, but I am having some error messages coming up. I have already installed the SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDocPlugin via nuget package, and the next step was for me to run the command bellow in the command prompt:

```
livingdoc feature-folder C:\Users\UserId\Desktop\Projects\ProjectName\Projects\Project.Tests.Automation -t C:\Users\userId\Desktop\Projects\ProjectName\Projects\Project.Tests.Automation\bin\DEV\net6.0\TestExecution.json
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
livingdoc : The term 'livingdoc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ livingdoc feature-folder C:\Users\UserId\Desktop\Projects\ProjectName ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (livingdoc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the [SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDoc.CLI](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow-livingdoc/en/latest/LivingDocGenerator/Installing-the-command-line-tool.html) tool globally? This is also needed alongside the Nuget package you've installed.

Try running the following command in a CMD window:
`dotnet tool install --global SpecFlow.Plus.LivingDoc.CLI`

Then open a new CMD window and try to generate the living docs again.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility here.

I was setting livingdoc as an External Tool, but to get it to run I had to browse to my:

```
 c:\Users\{MyUserName}\.dotnet\tools\livingdoc.exe
```

You can search for it by browsing.

Note, if you don't find it there, then its likely not installed globally or there's something different about the environment where you are running it.